# CardView not clickable

Tags: android, kotlin, pie-chart, cardview

In MainActivity, I have a pie chart, where the libary get from [GitHub - PhilJay/MPAndroidChart: A powerful Android chart view](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I add the pie chart into `cardView`.When `cardView` is clicked,  `toast` suppose to be displayed. But the `onClickListener` not working at all.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        showChart()

        cardView.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(application,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun showChart() {

        chart.setUsePercentValues(true)
        chart.description.isEnabled = false
        chart.center
        chart.extraRightOffset = 20f

        chart.isDrawHoleEnabled = true
        chart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE)

        chart.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.WHITE)
        chart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(10)

        chart.holeRadius = 58f
        chart.transparentCircleRadius = 46f

        chart.setDrawCenterText(true)

        chart.rotationAngle = 0f
        chart.isRotationEnabled = true
        chart.animateY(1400, Easing.EaseInOutQuad)

        val l = chart.legend
        l.verticalAlignment = Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.CENTER
        l.horizontalAlignment = Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT
        l.orientation = Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL
        l.setDrawInside(false)
        l.xOffset = 50f

        chart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.WHITE)
        chart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12f)
        setData(3,5)
    }

    private fun setData(numOpen: Int, numInProgress: Int) {
        val entries = ArrayList<PieEntry>()
        val colors = ArrayList<Int>()

        if (numOpen > 0) {
            entries.add(PieEntry(numOpen.toFloat(), "Open"))
            colors.add(ColorTemplate.rgb("#F44336"))

        }
        if (numInProgress > 0) {
            entries.add(PieEntry(numInProgress.toFloat(), "Progress"))
            colors.add(ColorTemplate.rgb("#2196F3"))
        }

        val dataSet = PieDataSet(entries, "Status")

        dataSet.sliceSpace = 3f
        dataSet.iconsOffset = MPPointF(0f, 40f)
        dataSet.selectionShift = 5f

        dataSet.colors = colors


        val data = PieData(dataSet)
        data.setValueFormatter(PercentFormatter(chart))
        data.setValueTextSize(11f)
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        chart.data = data

        // undo all highlights
        chart.highlightValues(null)
        chart.invalidate()
    }
}
```

**main_activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:id="@+id/chart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Could you comment showChart(), and then see if it is clickable? If empty card view is clickable then maybe your chart clicks are stoping card view  clicks.

Another way is to make LinearLayout Clickable, I think you want whole view to be clickable right?

Comment: @TheAnkush issue solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `PieChart` fully absorbing the `click` to interact with the chart elements, the click listener defined in the parent will not be called. Even If you set an `OnClickListener` to `PieChart`, it won't work. The solution to this problem is to set `onChartGestureListener` to `PieChart` and call your method from `onChartSingleTapped`.

**Example**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    cardView.setOnClickListener {
        doThis();
    }

    chart.onChartGestureListener = object : OnChartGestureListener {
        override fun onChartSingleTapped(me: MotionEvent?) {
            doThis()
        }
    }
}

fun doThis(){
    // your code goes here
}
```